# Python: if statement prints a particular variable

Tags: python, if-statement, formatting

I'm writing a Python exercise that calculates an average from 3 of your school subjects. After the average is calculated I want the program to find subjects that have less than 70 and print "You could improve in 'x' subject".

I know I could do it this way and write it out with specific `if statements`

```
if geometry < 70:
      print("Your geometry could be better")
elif algebra < 70: 
      print("Your algebra could be better")
etc etc
```

But I wondered if there was a more succinct answer, like

```
if geometry or algebra or physics < 70:
      print("Your", variable, "could be better")
```

I'm still at a beginners level of Python, is there an easier way to write out if statements and avoid those long lists?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of separate variables, then that will be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them in a dictionary:

```
grades = {'algebra': 57, 'geometry': 82, 'physics': 68}
for subject in grades:
    if grades[subject] < 70:
        print('Your {} could be better'.format(subject))
```

which can be condensed into a list comprehension using [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) in a single line!

```
[print("Your {} could be better".format(subject)) for subject, grade in grades.items() if grade < 70]
```

or for multiple subjects in the same sentence:

```
grades = {'algebra': 57, 'geometry': 82, 'physics': 68}
subjects = ' and '.join([subject for subject, grade in grades.items() if grade < 70]))
print('Your {} could be better'.format(subjects))
```

Comment: yeah, but too late.

Comment: Thanks! I should have also asked, if two subjects are less than 70, can i change it to 'geometry and physics need improving'?

Comment: Yes, use another to_improve list, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> subjects = {
...     'geometry': 80,
...     'algebra': 85,
...     'physics': 68
... }
... for subject, score in subjects.items():
...     if score < 70:
...         print('Your {} could be better'.format(subject))
... 
Your physics could be better
```

Comment: this is a rather trivial question (& answer) but answer is perfectly coded at least

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = {'geometry': 80, 'algebra': 85, 'physics': 68, 'chemistry': 50, 'biology': 69 }

to_improve = []
for subject, score in scores.items():
   if score < 70:
      to_improve.append(subject)
print ('Your', ' and '.join(to_improve), 'could be better')
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your code. Code only is not an answer.